# Socket.IO disconnecting and reconnnecting in loop

Tags: python, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a nodejs server running socket.io in order to upload files. My client (Python) is attempting to walk a directory of files, and upload them asynchronously. Although, while the loop is executing, I am seeing that the socket connection is randomly disconnecting and reconnecting as seen in these logs:

[Socket log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDul3.png)

It seems like the issue may be resource related, as the loop starts executing very quickly as expected and then disconnects. Additionally, my loop uploads each file asynchronously, so there may be too many concurrent connections for the client/sever/socket?

Here is my Python client code:

```
async def upload_dataset(self, directory, connection_id, order_id, aes_key):
        """Upload a dataset to the server

        :param str directory: Path to dataset folder to be uploaded.
        :param str connection_id: Base64 connection_id.
        :param str order_id: Base64 order_id.
        :param str aes_key: Base64 AES key.

        :return: Upload status code.
        """
        self.dataset_upload = True
        self.connect_to_socket()

        if isinstance(directory,str):
            if not os.path.isdir(directory):
                raise Exception("Path not a directory!") 
        else:
            raise Exception("Path must be a string!") 

        tasks = []

        for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(directory):
            for filename in filenames:
                file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                # print(file_path)
                tasks.append(self.upload_file(file_path, connection_id, order_id, aes_key))

        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print("FILES UPLOADED")
 
        self.disconnect_from_socket()
        return 201
```

All "upload_file" does is convert the file contents to bytes, emits the data to the socket, and waits for the "ack" message before returning. There is no logic in upload_file that would close the connection.

Here is my nodejs server code handling the socket connection:

```
const setupSocketConnection = (io) => {
  /* Socket connection */
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("A client connected");

    // Handle file data
    socket.on("file_data", async (payload) => {
      const status = await handleSocketUpload(payload);
      console.log(status);
      socket.emit("ack", "0");
    });

    // Handle disconnection
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("Client disconnected");
    });
  });
};
```

handleSocketUpload() returns almost immediately after the data comes in so this is not the source of the problem either.

Thank you for any help!